# Noun for 'a person that wants to please everyone'

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I am looking for a noun with the meaning:

> a person that wants to please everyone

In the sense that that person is inquisitive and intelligent, using said qualities to please others.

Example: Selflessly tries to stay friends with two parties that seem to loathe each other.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage.SE! Could you please provide us with a sentence illustrating how you would use the word as well as any research you might have done on the topic?

Comment: Are you looking for something like flatterer or mediator?

Comment: If you can update the post with the information @Cascabel recommended, you will be more likely to get answers. If you don't show research, like what words you've tried, people will be less willing to assist.

Comment: I like your question, but it seems you are not that much eager to get a good answer. please consider adding some information to your question. By the way, what do you think about *pleaser*: a person who tries to please or amuse?

Comment: A bigger problem is that what you ask for in the title seems to be at odds with what you ask for in the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps **altruist** will fit

> #### Altruist
>
> - a person unselfishly concerned for or devoted to the welfare of others (opposed to egoist ).

([Dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/altruist))

Answer (score 0):

the word ***conciliator*** carries a lot of the feelings you're describing along with it.

[from thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conciliator)

> con·cil·i·ate
>   1. To overcome the distrust or animosity of; appease. See Synonyms at pacify.
>
> 2. To regain or try to regain (friendship or goodwill) by pleasant behavior.
> 3. To make or attempt to make compatible; reconcile: tried to conciliate the conflicting theories.

or from [merriam-websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conciliate)

> Origin and Etymology of conciliate
>   Latin conciliatus, past participle of conciliare to assemble, unite, win over, from concilium assembly, council — more at council

Answer (score 0):

You may be referring to a ***charmer*** - one who has their way with almost anyone (that should include *pleasing* two parties that seem to loathe each other).

ODO:

> **[charmer](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/charmer)** *NOUN*
>
> A person with an attractive and engaging personality, typically one
>   who uses this to impress or manipulate others
>
> ‘He's a man who never does the right thing but somehow manages to win
>   people around because he's a charmer.’

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an adjective, it's fits the description. Maybe it can be of help.

> [**Amicable**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/amicable) (dictionary.com)

characterized by or showing goodwill; friendly; peaceable:
an amicable settlement.

See also the [Google](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=amicable) search results:

> (of relations between people) having a spirit of friendliness; without serious disagreement or rancor.
>   "there will be an amicable settlement of the dispute"

Answer (score 0):

I submit that **people pleaser** is the word you're in search of.  When used by psychologists, it functions as a single word (and if this were German, it would be a single word).  See this article in *Psychology Today*, below.  "People pleaser" gets at the motivating and animating elements of a persons psyche, which drive what they do and explain why they do what they do.

https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/shrink/201210/are-you-people-pleaser